# How to handle expand/collapse event of Html5 <details> element?

Tags: html, events, dropdown, expander

I use details/summary elements to get an expandable section:

https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_details.asp

```js
d3.select('details')
  .on('click',()=>{
     alert('clicked');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<details>
  <summary>Header</summary>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</details>
```

I want to execute an action when the open state of the details element is toggled. How can I do so?

If I would use the `onclick` event, the event is also fired if a user clicks on the summary or the content. I only want to handle "clicks on the toggle arrow".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
d3.select('details')
  .on('toggle',()=>{
     alert('clicked');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<details>
  <summary>Header</summary>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</details>
```

Comment: Or using plain vanilla js:

`document.querySelector('details').addEventListener('toggle', () => {});`

Answer (score 2):

### <s>[`summary::-webkit-details-marker`](http://www.otsukare.info/2016/04/19/summary-details)</s>

<s>`summary::-webkit-details-marker`</s> [`summary::marker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker) is the arrow you want, <del>unfortunately it's in the **shadow DOM** and access to that isn't cross-browser (Chrome only).</del>

**The following demo:**

- Hides the original arrow
- Replaced arrow with: `<b>▶</b>`
- Animated with CSS
- Basic JavaScript is applied to arrow

### Demo

```js
document.querySelector('summary b').onclick = function(e) {
  console.log('clicked');
};
```

```css
summary::marker {
  content: "";
}

summary {
  height: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

summary:focus {
  outline: none
}

summary b {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

[open] b {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transform-origin: 50% 45%;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary><b>▶</b>Header</summary>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</details>
```